# How to remove password saved by remember me option by browser using Angular.js and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have one issue in my password field and user name field using Angular.js.I have a login page.Suppose user clicked on `remember me` option of browser after the login.These saved user name and password is displaying on my username field and password field.I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">User Name :</span>
<div ng-class="{ 'myError': billdata.uname.$touched && billdata.uname.$invalid }">
<input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" class="form-control" placeholder="add user Name" ng-model="login_name" ng-minlength="6" ng-keypress="clearField('uname');" tabindex="6" >
</div>
</div>
<div class="help-block" ng-messages="billdata.uname.$error" ng-if="billdata.uname.$touched">
<p ng-message="minlength" style="color:#F00;">This field is too short.The min length of your user name should be 6.</p>
</div>

<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12" ng-hide="showpass">
<span style="position:absolute; right:5px; margin-top:6px; top:0px;"><button class="btn btn-xs btn-success"ng-mousedown="hideShowPassword();" ng-mouseup="hideShowPassword();" ng-mouseleave="hidePassAfterLeave();"  ><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button></span>
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Password :</span>
<div ng-class="{ 'myError': billdata.pass.$touched && billdata.pass.$invalid }">
<input type="{{inputType}}" name="pass" id="passno" class="form-control" placeholder="password" ng-model="password" ng-minlength="8" ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[_!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})/" ng-keypress="clearField('passno');" tabindex="7" >
</div>
```

The Login credentials used by user at the time of login is available where ever the username and password filed is found which i dont need.Here I need blank user name and password field even the user clicked `remember me` option of browser.Please help me to resolve this issue .

Comment: Who and how was saved it by `remember me` option? Ask him :)

Comment: Most likely, if you are seeing the login screen, the username and password is being saved by the browser and not your app.  If you successfully logged in and the remember me option was saved server side, the common behavior is to have you stay logged in

Comment: What are you call `remember me option`? Browser's `saved passwords`? Or your own checkbox, to save login/pass into cookie/localstorage?

Comment: I dont need to display those credentials in the password as well as user name field.

Comment: If you're about browser's feature - it's not your responsibility. You should not to modify expected behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add 2 hidden inputs to start of your form:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
    <div style="display: none;">
     <input type="text" id="PreventChromeAutocomplete"
      name="PreventChromeAutocomplete" autocomplete="username" />
     <input type="password" id="PreventChromePasswordAutocomplete"
      name="PreventChromePasswordAutocomplete" autocomplete="password" />
    </div>
    <!-- Rest form -->        
</form>
```

Comment: @ vp_arth : If i am doing user name field as read only its not coming.

Comment: try to put it into the form

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<input type="password" autocomplete="off" />
```

try adding autocomplete="off" on your form also

```
<form autocomplete="off" ...></form>
```

Comment: Google Chrome is excessive smart for this. This will be ignored.

Comment: There is work around mentioned in this bug trail https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153. try #14

Answer (score 0):

Try using javascript as :

```
$('#passno').attr("autocomplete", "off");
```

or add `(autocomplete="off")` attribute in html input tag :

For more info, refer http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Try same for username field as well. :)

Comment: Same answer.. It works not in modern browsers. Because passwords is not `autocomplete`

Comment: please try <input type="password" style="display:none">